# Left Join Lateral and array aggregates

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.3

I'm using Postgres 9.3.

I have two tables `T1`  and `T2` and a `n:m` relation `T1_T2_rel` between them. Now I'd like to create a view that in addition to the columns of T1 provides a column that, for each record in T1, contains an array with the primary key ids of all related records of T2. If there are no related entries in T2, corresponding fields of this column shall contain null-values.

An abstracted version of my schema would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 ( t1_id serial primary key, t1_data int );

CREATE TABLE T2 ( t2_id serial primary key );

CREATE TABLE T1_T2_rel (
  t1_id int references T1( t1_id )
, t2_id int references T2( t2_id )
);
```

Corresponding sample data could be generated as follows:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (t1_data)
SELECT cast(random()*100 as int) FROM generate_series(0,9) c(i);

INSERT INTO T2 (t2_id) SELECT nextval('T2_t2_id_seq') FROM generate_series(0,99);

INSERT INTO T1_T2_rel
SELECT cast(random()*10 as int) % 10 + 1 as t1_id
     , cast(random()*99+1 as int) as t2_id
FROM   generate_series(0,99);
```

So far, I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT T1.t1_id, T1.t1_data, agg
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT t1_id, array_agg(t2_id) as agg
   FROM T1_T2_rel
   WHERE t1_id=T1.t1_id
   GROUP BY t1_id
   ) as temp ON temp.t1_id=T1.t1_id;
```

This works. However, can it be simplified?

A corresponding fiddle can be found here: [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cd38a/2). Unfortunately, sql-fiddle does not support Postgres 9.3 (yet) which is required for lateral joins.

[**Update**] As has been pointed out, a simple `left join` using a subquery in principle is enough. However, If I compare the query plans, Postgres resorts to sequential scans on the aggregated tables when using a `left join` whereas index scans are used in the case of the `left join lateral`.

Comment: Could you put up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12) with simple data samples, for anyone willing to take a shot at this problem to work with?

Comment: Wouldn't a normal left join group by t1_id work too?

Comment: Indeed, it does. Thanks, @Denis

Comment: In this case it suffices. However, I abstracted away too much. ;-) The productive code has a third table T3 and another n:m relation between T1 and T3 which I'd like to aggregate in the same way. With another left join, each key from the third table appears as many times in the second aggregate as there are entries in the T1_T2-relation and vice versa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Denis already commented: no need for `LATERAL`.
Also, your subquery selected the wrong column. This works:

```
SELECT t1.t1_id, t1.t1_data, t2_ids
FROM   t1
LEFT   JOIN (
    SELECT t1_id, array_agg(t2_id) AS t2_ids
    FROM   t1_t2_rel
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) sub USING (t1_id);
```

[**-SQL fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/98a3a/1)

#### Performance and testing

Concerning the ensuing sequential scan you mention: If you query the whole table, a sequential scan is often *faster*. Depends on the version you are running, your hardware, your settings and statistics of cardinalities and distribution of your data. Experiment with selective `WHERE` clauses like `WHERE t1.t1_id < 1000` or `WHERE t1.t1_id = 1000` and combine with [planner settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE) to learn about choices:

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
SET enable_indexscan = off;
```

To reset:

```
RESET enable_seqscan;
RESET enable_indexscan;
```

Only in your local session, mind you! [This related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27681/unexpected-seq-scan-when-doing-query-against-boolean-with-value-null/27693#27693) has more instructions.
Of course, your setting may be off, too:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/how-can-i-avoid-postgresql-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan-for-one-of-two-ne/8229000#8229000)