# postgresql not using trigram index on text column but uses it on varchar column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, trigram

So basically I set up a very simple test table to test trigram and fulltext indexing capabilities in postgresql 9.1 (stock Debian stable).

Here are the table and index definitions:

```
-- Table: fulltextproba
-- DROP TABLE fulltextproba;
CREATE TABLE fulltextproba
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  text text,
  varchar600 character varying(600) COLLATE pg_catalog."C.UTF-8",
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

-- Index: id_index
-- DROP INDEX id_index;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_index
  ON fulltextproba
  USING btree
  (id );

-- Index: text_gin_fulltext_hun
-- DROP INDEX text_gin_fulltext_hun;
CREATE INDEX text_gin_fulltext_hun
  ON fulltextproba
  USING gin
  (to_tsvector('hungarian'::text, text) );

-- Index: text_gin_trgm
-- DROP INDEX text_gin_trgm;
CREATE INDEX text_gin_trgm
  ON fulltextproba
  USING gin
  (text COLLATE pg_catalog."C.UTF-8" gin_trgm_ops);

-- Index: varchar600
-- DROP INDEX varchar600;
CREATE INDEX varchar600
  ON fulltextproba
  USING btree
  (varchar600 COLLATE pg_catalog."C.UTF-8" varchar_pattern_ops);

-- Index: varchar600_gin_trgm
-- DROP INDEX varchar600_gin_trgm;
CREATE INDEX varchar600_gin_trgm
  ON fulltextproba
  USING gin
  (varchar600 COLLATE pg_catalog."C.UTF-8" gin_trgm_ops);
```

My problem is, if I do a `%foo%` search that should use the trigram index, If I search on the text column, it doesn't:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM public.fulltextproba WHERE text LIKE '%almáv%'
 count 
-------
   396
(1 row)

real    0m7.215s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.004s
                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=657056.11..657056.12 rows=1 width=4)
   ->  Seq Scan on fulltextproba  (cost=0.00..657052.72 rows=1355 width=4)
         Filter: (text ~~ '%almáv%'::text)
(3 rows)
```

But if I search in the varchar600 column, it does use the trigram index, and is - not suprisingly - much faster:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM public.fulltextproba WHERE varchar600 LIKE '%almáv%'
 count 
-------
   373
(1 row)

real    0m0.184s
user    0m0.052s
sys 0m0.004s
                                         QUERY PLAN                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=5283.11..5283.12 rows=1 width=4)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on fulltextproba  (cost=62.50..5279.73 rows=1355 width=4)
         Recheck Cond: ((varchar600)::text ~~ '%almáv%'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on varchar600_gin_trgm  (cost=0.00..62.16 rows=1355 width=0)
               Index Cond: ((varchar600)::text ~~ '%almáv%'::text)
(5 rows)
```

So the ultimate questions are:

- Why postgres doesn't use the trigram index on the text column.
- How can postgres be made to use the index? Should I define it some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text` is perfectly fine. The best option even, as you can see in the `EXPLAIN` output:

```
Index Cond: ((varchar600)::text ~~ '%almáv%'::text)
```

#### Collation mismatch

The immediate reason is probably a **collation mismatch**. Your table is defined:

```
text text,   -- default collation is ???
varchar600 character varying(600) COLLATE pg_catalog."C.UTF-8"
```

While both indexes use `COLLATE pg_catalog."C.UTF-8"`. What is your default collation? The output from:

```
SHOW LC_COLLATE;
```

You may be mixing different collations. Retest with:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM public.fulltextproba
WHERE text COLLATE pg_catalog."C.UTF-8" LIKE '%almáv%'
```

[Read about collation support in Postgres.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html)

#### General problems in your test

You obviously have different values in either of the columns. Repeat the test with *identical* values.

To force Postgres into using the index, you can (for debugging in your session only!):

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
```

Then try again. Details:

- [Left Join Lateral and array aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490861/postgres-left-join-lateral-and-array-aggregates/19503840#19503840)

#### Outlook for GIN index in Postgres 9.4

The upcoming Postgres 9.4 is shipping with a number of substantial improvements for GIN indexes. In particular, they are going to be much smaller and faster.

- [GIN index in the release notes for 9.4.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/release-9-4.html#AEN118635)
- [PDF from PGCon by some of the authors discussing the new features.](http://www.pgcon.org/2014/schedule/attachments/329_PGCon2014-GIN.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, you were right! My locale is `hu_HU.UTF-8`, and by specifying the collation, the trigram index has begun to be used right away (my reason for using `C.UTF-8` was that this column contains multilingual text).

Comment: As for the size of the table, you are wrong: the table contains 14155098 (~14M) rows, so the index scan is rightly faster.

Comment: To the other point: I know there are different values in each column (the `varchar600` column is truncated to 600 chars; it only matters for about 10% of the rows), so I have no problem with the difference in the result. I am not testing whether postgres conveys accurate or consistent results (I am assuming that, I may be wrong :) ), I am trying to assess general performance for some basic queries in a certain environment to test the feasibility of using postgres. So far it fares well. :)

Comment: Also, changing the default collation for `test` made the original query use the index. Setting the collation took two hours... :-P 

Moral: Choose your collations wisely, and _in advance_!

Comment: @P.Péter: I mistook the rowcount for the hits as the number of rows in the ANALYZE output. Removed that part. Still confused though, why we see `rows=1355`, but get a much smaller number from `count()`. I also added an outlook for GIN indexes in Postgres 9.4, which you may like.

Comment: I think that `rows=1355` is a preliminary set of rows found by the trigram index, which is further refined by a filter.