# How to prevent changing of execution plan for certain values

Tags: sql, postgresql, explain

I have a table in `PosgreSQL 9.1.9`. There's a schema:

```
CREATE TABLE chpl_text
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('chpl_text_id_seq1'::regclass),
  page_id bigint NOT NULL,
  page_idx integer NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

I have around 40000000 (40M) rows in this table.
Now, there's a query:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM chpl_text
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 100000
OFFSET N
```

Everything runs smoothly for `N <= 5300000`. Execution plan looks like this

```
Limit  (cost=12743731.26..12984179.02 rows=100000 width=52)
  ->  Index Scan using chpl_text_pkey on chpl_text t  (cost=0.00..96857560.86 rows=40282164 width=52)
```

But for `N >= 5400000` it magically changes into

```
Limit  (cost=13042543.16..13042793.16 rows=100000 width=52)
  ->  Sort  (cost=13029043.16..13129748.57 rows=40282164 width=52)
        Sort Key: id
        ->  Seq Scan on chpl_text t  (cost=0.00..1056505.64 rows=40282164 width=52)
```

Resulting in very long runtime.

How can I prevent postresql from changeing query plan for higher offsets?

Note: I am aware, that big offsets are not good at all, but I am forced to use them here.

Comment: Are you using the default configuration values? You should try to increase the ammount of work_mem and other memory related parameters.

Comment: As per postgres DOC (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) this is expected. See a similar post here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/32956/execution-plan-in-simple-query-in-pgsql-depends-on-offset-clause-why.

Comment: Can you repeat those with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) ?

Answer (score 1):

If Postgres is configured halfway decently, your statistics are up to date (`ANALYZE` or  autovacuum) and the cost settings are sane, Postgres generally knows *better* when to do an index scan or a sequential scan. Details and links:
[Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/how-can-i-avoid-postgresql-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan-for-one-of-two-ne/8229000#8229000)

To actually test performance without sequential scan, "disable" it (in a debug session only!)

```
SET enable_seqscan=OFF;
```

[More in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE)

Then run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` again ...

Also, [the release of **Postgres 9.2** had a focus on "big data"](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1415/). With your given use case you should urgently consider upgrading to the [current release](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

You can also try this **alternative query** with a CTE and `row_number()` and see if the query plan turns out more favorable:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT ..., row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
   FROM   chpl_text
   )
SELECT ...
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn BETWEEN N+1 AND N+100000
ORDER  BY id;
```

That's not always the case, but might be in your special situation.