# Why is Postgres not using index on a simple GROUP BY?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, group-by

I have created a 36M rows table with an index on `type` column:

```
CREATE TABLE items AS
  SELECT
    (random()*36000000)::integer AS id,
    (random()*10000)::integer AS type,
    md5(random()::text) AS s
  FROM
    generate_series(1,36000000);
CREATE INDEX items_type_idx ON items USING btree ("type");
```

I run this simple query and expect postgresql to use my index:

```
explain select count(*) from "items" group by "type";
```

But the query planner decides to use Seq Scan instead:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=734592.00..734627.90 rows=3590 width=12) (actual time=6477.913..6478.344 rows=3601 loops=1)
  Group Key: type
  ->  Seq Scan on items  (cost=0.00..554593.00 rows=35999800 width=4) (actual time=0.044..1820.522 rows=36000000 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.107 ms
Execution time: 6478.525 ms
```

*Time without EXPLAIN:* 5s 979ms

I have tried several solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143463/why-is-postgres-scanning-a-huge-table-instead-of-using-my-index):

- Run `VACUUM ANALYZE` or `VACUUM ANALYZE`
- Configure `default_statistics_target`, `random_page_cost`, `work_mem`

but nothing helps apart from setting `enable_seqscan = OFF`:

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
explain select count(*) from "items" group by "type";

GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..1114880.46 rows=3590 width=12) (actual time=5.637..5256.406 rows=3601 loops=1)
  Group Key: type
  ->  Index Only Scan using items_type_idx on items  (cost=0.56..934845.56 rows=35999800 width=4) (actual time=0.074..2783.896 rows=36000000 loops=1)
        Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.103 ms
Execution time: 5256.667 ms
```

*Time without EXPLAIN:* 659ms

Query with index scan is about 10x faster on my machine.

Is there a better solution than setting `enable_seqscan`?

**UPD1**

My postgresql version is 9.6.3, work_mem = 4MB (tried 64MB), random_page_cost = 4 (tried 1.1), max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0 (tried 4).

**UPD2**

I have tried to fill *type* column not with random numbers, but with `i / 10000` to make `pg_stats.correlation` = 1 - still seqscan.

**UPD3**

@jgh is 100% right:

> This typically only happens when the table's row width is much wider than some indexes

I've made large column `data` and now postgres use index. Thanks everyone!

Comment: What's your PostgreSQL version? Also, please provide output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0c5c410657513d1bda7f2e21a4d36eb9 - just compare actual timing for `enable_seqscan = ON` and `enable_seqscan = OFF`

Comment: What are your settings for work_mem and random_page_cost? [and : why doesn't the table have a Primary Key?]

Comment: Note:I have work_mem very low (4M) and random_page_cost= 1.1 (I have an SSD), and I get an index scan without fiddling the switches.

Comment: I think this index can be meaningfull on requests like `select "type", count(*) from "items" group by "type";` Why to use group by to count all records?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) wiki says

> It is important to realise that the planner is concerned with
>   minimising the total cost of the query. With databases, the cost of
>   I/O typically dominates. For that reason, "count(*) without any
>   predicate" queries will only use an index-only scan **if the index is
>   significantly smaller than its table. This typically only happens when
>   the table's row width is much wider than some indexes'**.

and

> Index-only scans are only used when the planner surmises that that
>   **will reduce the total amount of I/O required, according to its
>   imperfect cost-based modelling**. This all heavily depends on visibility
>   of tuples, if an index would be used anyway (i.e. how selective a
>   predicate is, etc), and if there is actually an index available that
>   could be used by an index-only scan in principle

Accordingly, your index is not considered "significantly smaller" and the entire dataset is to be read, which leads the planner in using a seq scan

Comment: This is good to know, but still a little confusing. I have a table that is 56GB and a column index that is 1.5GB. When I run a group by using only the indexed column, the query planner still bypasses the index and uses a seq scan.