# PostgreSQL: How to select on non-aggregating column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, having

Seems like a simple question but I'm having trouble accomplishing it. What I want to do is return all names that have duplicate ids. The view looks as such:

```
id |  name  | other_col
---+--------+----------
 1 | James  |    x
 2 | John   |    x
 2 | David  |    x
 3 | Emily  |    x
 4 | Cameron|    x
 4 | Thomas |    x
```

And so in this case, I'd just want the result:

```
name
-------
John
David
Cameron
Thomas
```

The following query works but it seems like an overkill to have two separate selects:

```
select name 
from view where id = ANY(select id from view 
                         WHERE other_col='x' 
                         group by id 
                         having count(id) > 1) 
      and other_col='x';
```

I believe it should be possible to do something under the lines of:

```
select name from view WHERE other_col='x' group by id, name having count(id) > 1;
```

But this returns nothing at all! What is the 'proper' query?

Do I just have to it like my first working suggestion or is there a better way?

Comment: a CTE may work nicely for you.

Comment: Are you simply trying to avoid using more than one `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @Nicarus Yes. I want to remove the redundant 
WHERE other_col='x' (the real conditions are quite long) so removing 1 `SELECT` will make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state you want to avoid two "queries", which isn't really possible. There are plenty of solutions available, but I would use a CTE like so:

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    other_col,
    COUNT(name) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS id_count
FROM
    table
)

SELECT name FROM cte WHERE id_count > 1;
```

You can reuse the CTE, so you don't have to duplicate logic and I personally find it easier to read and understand what it is doing.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks Nicarus, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Good one. BTW, I have studied Temp Tables and derived tables are good in performance when comparing with CTE, am i right?

Comment: @MuthaiahPL - In my experience it depends on what you are doing, but temp tables do allow for such things as adding indexes - CTEs do not. In this case the question was not about performance, but simplicity of writing the query, which I believe the CTE provides.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name FROM Table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*)>1) Temp
```

Comment: This is pretty much identical to what I suggested and I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this...

Comment: May i know in what terms you are looking for a better way?

Comment: Specifically, I just want to be able to know if this can be done in a single query because I'd rather not have to repeat two separate selects (if possible). The actual where conditions are quite long and I'd like to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXIST operator

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT null FROM table t2
  WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
    AND t1.name <> t2.name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```
select distinct name 
from view v1
join view v2 on v1.id = v2.id
  and v1.name != v2.name
```

The use of `distinct` is there in case there are more than 2 rows sharing the same `id`. If that's not possible, you can omit `distinct`.

---

A note: Naming a column `id` when it's not unique will likely cause confusion, because it's the industry standard for the unique identifier column. If there isn't a unique column at all, it will cause coding difficulties.

Comment: This isn't a bad suggestion but it happens that my view is large so I'd have to go `on v1.id = v2.id AND v1.other_col='x' AND v2.other_col='x'` and it takes longer than the accepted answer. About the `id`, I will make sure to name my columns more appropriately in future questions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use a CTE. That's typically more expensive because Postgres has to materialize the intermediary result.

An [**`EXISTS`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join is typically fastest for this. Just make sure to repeat predicates (or match the values):

```
SELECT name 
FROM   view v
WHERE  other_col = 'x'
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM view 
   WHERE  other_col = 'x' -- or: other_col = v.other_col
   AND    id <> v.id      -- exclude join to self
   );
```

That's a *single* query, even if you see the keyword `SELECT` twice here. An `EXISTS` expression does not produce a derived table, it will be resolved to simple index look-ups.

Speaking of which: a multicolumn index on `(other_col, id)` should help. Depending on data distribution and access patterns, appending the payload column `name` to enable index-only scans might help: `(other_col, id, name)`. Or even a partial index, ***if*** `other_col = 'x'` is a constant predicate:

```
CREATE INDEX ON view (id) WHERE other_col = 'x';
```

- [PostgreSQL does not use a partial index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030354/postgresql-does-not-use-a-partial-index/26031289#26031289)

The upcoming Postgres 9.6 would even allow an index-only scan on the partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON view (id, name) WHERE other_col = 'x';
```

You will *love* this improvement ([quoting the /devel manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-9-6.html)):

> Allow using an [index-only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html) with a partial index when the index's
>   predicate involves column(s) not stored in the index (Tomas Vondra,
>   Kyotaro Horiguchi)
>
> An index-only scan is now allowed if the query mentions such columns
>   only in `WHERE` clauses that match the index predicate

Verify performance with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT ...`
Run a couple of times to rule out caching effects.