# Return all the rows for id's that have all three seq number present

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, relational-division

I have a table which looks something like this:

`table1`

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | seq | test |
+----+-----+------+
|  1 |   1 | HR   |
|  1 |   2 | RR   |
|  2 |   1 | HR   |
|  2 |   2 | RR   |
|  2 |   3 | OXY  |
|  3 |   1 | HR   |
|  3 |   2 | RR   |
|  4 |   1 | HR   |
|  4 |   2 | RR   | 
|  4 |   3 | OXY  | 
+----+-----+------+
```

I would like to get the result table like below. That is I need to have all the rows of a particular id only if all the three seq number is present for a particular id:

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | seq | test |
+----+-----+------+
|  2 |   1 | HR   |
|  2 |   2 | RR   |
|  2 |   3 | OXY  |
|  4 |   1 | HR   |
|  4 |   2 | RR   |
|  4 |   3 | OXY  | 
+----+-----+------+
```

I am looking forward to write a plpgsql function which gives me the solution. I am relatively new to plpgsql and programming in general. It would be great if someone help me out in getting the result.

So far this is what my function looks like and it is incomplete:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
returns SETOF table1 AS $$
DECLARE
    cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT *
        FROM table1
        ORDER by id;
    rec_cur RECORD;
    counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

BEGIN 
    OPEN cur;

    FETCH FIRST FROM cur INTO rec_cur;
    MOVE RELATIVE +1 FROM cur;

    LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO rec_cur;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

        IF rec_cur.seq = 1 AND counter = 0 THEN
        RETURN NEXT rec_cursor;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
    RETURN;

END ; $$ 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Comment: If you put your table in code blocks it will stay formatted

Comment: Thank you so much. I was just about to do that. Anyways thank you :)

Comment: As always, an actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) would help to clarify. Most importantly: Is `(id, seq)` defined unique and both columns not null? Any other reliable meta info? And always mention your Postgres version. [Edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you so much for the info. I would definitely consider the points which you have mentioned when I ask the next question.

Answer (score 2):

A cursor is definitely not the right approach.  You can the ids easily using aggregation and `having`:

```
select id
from t
where seq in (1, 2, 3)
group by id
having count(seq) = 3;
```

Then to get the original rows, there are multiple ways:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select id
      from t
      where seq in (1, 2, 3)
      group by id
      having count(seq) = 3
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id;
```

EDIT:

If the sequence numbers always start at 1 and have no gaps, then window functions are the way to go:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(t.seq) over (partition by t.id) as maxseq
      from t
     ) t
where maxseq = 3;
```

Comment: Since `seq` could only have a value from `1, 2, 3`, would `where seq in (1, 2, 3)` have any effect?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour . . . The question does not clearly specify that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete.
**If** we can assume the existence of rows with `seq = 1` and `seq = 2` if there is a row with `seq = 3` for the same `id`, then it becomes cheap and simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE seq = 3) x
JOIN   table1 t USING (id)
-- ORDER BY id, seq;  -- unclear whether you need sorted output.
```

Also assuming `(id, seq)` to be defined `UNIQUE` and both column `NOT NULL`.

If you need to **optimize read performance**, add a partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON table1 (id) WHERE seq = 3;
```

[Since Postgres 9.6 this can be used in an *index-only* scan.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html#AEN131499)

And you need an index on `(id)` of course. The index on `(id, seq)` which exists if you have said `UNIQUE` constraint does the job as well. Related:

- [Does a Postgres UNIQUE constraint imply an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655439/does-a-postgres-unique-constraint-imply-an-index/29655542#29655542)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)
- [PostgreSQL does not use a partial index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030354/postgresql-does-not-use-a-partial-index/26031289#26031289)

Either way, it's a case of [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division). here is an arsenal of techniques to identify qualifying `id`'s if we can't assume sequential values in `seq`:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

Comment: The table is such a way that, for a unique id for sure there is seq=1 and seq=2 which corresponds to test=HR and test=RR. But for some id's there are seq=3 which correspond to test=OXY. I am interested in only the id's which has all the 3 seq's. 
And also both the columns do not have NULL values.

The additional info. is really great and i appreciate that. Thank you again.