# How can I prioritize one index over another?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1='value1' AND column2='value2';
```

I have an index for `column1` and another for `column2`.

How do I tell Postgres to prefer the second index? Should I put it first?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot tell Postgres directly which index to prefer. It wouldn't make sense, either, except for rare corner cases.

- The order of expressions in the `WHERE` clause is *completely* irrelevant. The query planner will apply predicates as it sees fit.
- You are not limited to use just one index. Postgres can use *both* an combine them with bitmap index scans. Details in this related answer on dba.SE:

  - [PostgreSQL versus MySQL for EAV structures storage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14965/3684)

  But its often more effective to use just *one* index and filter the rest.
- Finally, you can create a single multicolumn index over *both* columns for optimized performance. Like:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX foo ON tbl (column1, column2);
  ```

  - [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

  Or even a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) if one of your predicates is constant (most or all queries restrict to `column2 = 'constant_value'`) and this selection is substantially smaller than the whole table:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX foo ON tbl (column1) WHERE column2 = 'constant_value';
  ```

If Postgres makes bad choices for query plans, there is typically something off in your database:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/how-can-i-avoid-postgresql-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan-for-one-of-two-ne/8229000?s=2|0.5490#8229000)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

My problem is that i have a big OR for column1:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1='value1' OR column1='value3' OR ...) AND column2='value2';

an also, my column2 is UNIQUE... 

If i do an index on both columns i dont want postgres to look for all the combinations, like:

column1 = 'value1' AND column2='value2'
column1 = 'value3' AND column2='value2'
....

Thank you anyway, now i know that i cant priorize indexes, i will put two indexes and trust the postgres power

Comment: @GuidoSoferInglesi: Well, that's quite a different question then. I suppose you start a *new question* that has all the necessary details, including the table definition with existing indexes, your query, your version of Postgres and the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. There may be room for optimization.