# GIN index not used for small table when 0 rows returned

Tags: postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching, postgresql-performance

In a Postgres 9.4 database, I created a GIN trigram index on a table called 'persons' that contains 1514 rows like the following:

```
CREATE INDEX persons_index_name_1 ON persons
USING gin (lower(name) gin_trgm_ops);
```

and a query that looks for similar names as follows:

```
select name, last_name from persons where lower(name) % 'thename'
```

So, I first issued a query with a name I knew beforehand that would have similar matches, so the `explain analyze` showed that the index I created was used in this query:

```
select name, last_name from persons where lower(name) % 'george'
```

And the results were the expected:

```
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on persons  (cost=52.01..58.72 rows=2 width=26) (actual time=0.054..0.065 rows=1 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (lower((name)::text) % 'george'::text)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 2
        Heap Blocks: exact=1
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on persons_index_name_1  (cost=0.00..52.01 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=3 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (lower((name)::text) % 'george'::text)
...
Execution time: 1.382 ms"
```

So, out of curiosity, I wanted to see if the index was used when the `thename` parameter contained a name that didn't exist at all in the table:

```
select name, last_name from persons where lower(name) % 'noname'
```

But I saw that in this case that the index was not used at all and the execution time was way higher:

```
  ->  Seq Scan on persons  (cost=0.00..63.72 rows=2 width=26) (actual time=6.494..6.494 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (lower((name)::text) % 'noname'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1514
...
Execution time: 7.387 ms
```

As a test, I tried the same with a GIST index and in both cases, the index was used and the execution time was like the first case above.

I went ahead and recreated the table but this time inserting 10014 rows; and I saw that in both cases above, the GIN index was used and the execution time was the best for those cases.

Why is a GIN index is not used when the query above returns no results in a table with not so much rows (1514 in my case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigram indexes are **case insensitive**, test with:

```
select 'case' <-> 'CASE' AS ci1
     , 'case' %   'CASE' AS ci2
     , 'CASE' <-> 'CASE' AS c1
     , 'CASE' %   'CASE' AS c2;
```

So you might as well just:

```
CREATE INDEX persons_index_name_1 ON persons USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

And:

```
select name, last_name from persons where name % 'thename';
```

As to your actual question, for small tables an index look-up might not pay. That's exactly what your added tests demonstrate. And establishing that *nothing* matches can be more expensive than finding some matches.

Aside from that, your cost setting and / or table statistics may not be at their respective optimum to let Postgres pick the most adequate query plans.

The expected cost numbers translate to *much* higher actual cost for the sequential scan than for the bitmap index scan. You may be overestimating the cost of index scans as compared to sequential scans. [`random_page_cost`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) (and [`cpu_index_tuple_cost`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS) may be set too high and `effective_cache_size` too low.

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

Comment: Thank you very much Erwin. Really appreciate the fact that you mentioned that the trigram indexes are case insensitive. That solves a big issue I had. I'll definitely take a look at the `random_page_cost` and `cpu_index_tuple_cost`.