# Prevent usage of index for a particular query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I have a slow query in a Postgres DB. Using `explain analyze`, I can see that Postgres makes bitmap index scan on two different indexes followed by bitmap AND on the two resulting sets.

Deleting one of the indexes makes the evaluation ten times faster (bitmap index scan is still used on the first index). However, that deleted index is useful in other queries.

Query:

```
select
  booking_id
from
  booking
where
  substitute_confirmation_token is null
  and date_trunc('day', from_time) >= cast('01/25/2016 14:23:00.004' as date)
  and from_time >= '01/25/2016 14:23:00.004'
  and type = 'LESSON_SUBSTITUTE'
  and valid
order by
  booking_id;
```

Indexes:

```
"idx_booking_lesson_substitute_day" btree (date_trunc('day'::text, from_time)) WHERE valid AND type::text = 'LESSON_SUBSTITUTE'::text
"booking_substitute_confirmation_token_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (substitute_confirmation_token)
```

Query plan:

```
Sort  (cost=287.26..287.26 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=711.371..711.377 rows=44 loops=1)
  Sort Key: booking_id
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
  Buffers: shared hit=8 read=7437 written=1
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on booking  (cost=275.25..287.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=711.255..711.294 rows=44 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((date_trunc('day'::text, from_time) >= '2016-01-25'::date) AND valid AND ((type)::text = 'LESSON_SUBSTITUTE'::text) AND (substitute_confirmation_token IS NULL))
        Filter: (from_time >= '2016-01-25 14:23:00.004'::timestamp without time zone)
        Buffers: shared hit=5 read=7437 written=1
        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=275.25..275.25 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=711.224..711.224 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=5 read=7433 written=1
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_booking_lesson_substitute_day  (cost=0.00..20.50 rows=594 width=0) (actual time=0.080..0.080 rows=72 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (date_trunc('day'::text, from_time) >= '2016-01-25'::date)
                    Buffers: shared hit=5 read=1
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on booking_substitute_confirmation_token_key  (cost=0.00..254.50 rows=13594 width=0) (actual time=711.102..711.102 rows=2718734 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (substitute_confirmation_token IS NULL)
                    Buffers: shared read=7432 written=1
Total runtime: 711.436 ms
```

Can I prevent using a particular index for a particular query in Postgres?

Comment: I take it `booking_substitute_confirmation_token_key` is the one you want to "disable"?

Comment: @jakub-kania Yes. Btw. I just tried to replace the index by `create unique index booking_substitute_confirmation_unique on booking(substitute_confirmation_token) where substitute_confirmation_token is not null` and that speeds up the evaluation from 711 to 10 ms.

Comment: Show `EXECUTE (analyze, buffers)`, not just `EXECUTE`.

Comment: Your statistics seems off for `booking`, try to `VACUUM ANALYZE` this table.

Comment: Well, I ended up with replacing the unique constraint (and related default index `booking_substitute_confirmation_token_key`) by unique index with a predicate as shown in my comment above. This seems to be a perfect solution for me. This unique index excludes rows where the indexed attribute has null value. The table has few millions of rows and just few thousands of rows with not null values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Your clever solution

For your particular case, a partial unique index that only covers rare values, so Postgres won't (can't) use the index for the common `NULL` value.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX booking_substitute_confirmation_uni
ON booking (substitute_confirmation_token)
WHERE substitute_confirmation_token IS NOT NULL;
```

It's a textbook use-case for a partial index. [*Literally!*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3) The manual has a similar example and this perfectly matching advice to go with it:

> Finally, a partial index can also be used to override the system's
> query plan choices. Also, data sets with peculiar distributions might
> cause the system to use an index when it really should not. In that
> case the index can be set up so that it is not available for the
> offending query. Normally, PostgreSQL makes reasonable choices about
> index usage (e.g., it avoids them when retrieving common values, so
> the earlier example really only saves index size, it is not required
> to avoid index usage), and grossly incorrect plan choices are cause
> for a bug report.
>
> Keep in mind that setting up a partial index indicates that you know
> at least as much as the query planner knows, in particular you know
> when an index might be profitable. Forming this knowledge requires
> experience and understanding of how indexes in PostgreSQL work. In
> most cases, the advantage of a partial index over a regular index
> will be minimal. There are cases where they are quite counterproductive [...]

You commented:

> The table has few millions of rows and just few thousands of rows with not null values.

So it's a perfect use-case. It will even speed up queries on non-null values for `substitute_confirmation_token` because the index is *much* smaller now.

### Answer to question

To answer your original question: it's not possible to "disable" an existing index for a particular query. You would have to drop it, but that's way too expensive.

#### Fake drop index

You *could* drop an index inside a transaction, run your `SELECT` and then, instead of committing, use `ROLLBACK`. That's *fast*, but be aware that ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropindex.html)):

> A normal `DROP INDEX` acquires exclusive lock on the table, blocking
> other accesses until the index drop can be completed.

So this is no good for regular use in multi-user environments.

```
BEGIN;
DROP INDEX big_user_id_created_at_idx;
SELECT ...;
ROLLBACK;  -- so the index is preserved after all
```

See:

- [Query with smaller subset to scan taking exponentially longer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/325208/3684)

#### More detailed statistics

Normally, though, it should be enough to raise the `STATISTICS` target for the column, so Postgres can more reliably identify common values and avoid the index for those. Try:

```
ALTER TABLE booking ALTER COLUMN substitute_confirmation_token SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

Then: `ANALYZE booking;` before you try your query again. 1000 is an example value. Related:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)