# Can SQL index make search longer?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

I heard this question during a job interview, and the interviewer said that yes. My question is why and could someone give an example of an index that makes search longer instead of shorter.

Comment: This is a question without context, so basically unanswerable.

Comment: Longer... than what?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it ***can***.

An additional index adds possible execution plans for a query if applicable. The Postgres query planner estimates costs for a variety of possible plans and the fastest estimate wins. Since those are *estimates*, actual query plans can always deviate. A chosen query plan using your new index can turn out to be slower than another plan without.
If your server is configured properly (cost and resource settings, current columns statistics, ...) this outcome is unlikely, but still possible. This can happen for almost every query. More likely for more complex queries. And some types of queries are notoriously hard to estimate.

Related:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

Also, indexes always add write cost, so if your database is write-heavy and the machine is already saturated, more indexes can bring overall performance down.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial example would be on a table with very few rows.

An index search has to load the index into memory and then look up the original data.  If a table has only a few rows, they probably fit onto one data page.  So, a full table scan requires loading one page.

Any index search (on a cold cache) requires loading two data pages -- one for the index and one for the data.  That can be (significantly) longer then just scanning the rows on a single page.

On a large table, if the "search" returns a significant proportion of the rows in the table, then an index search ends up fetching the rows in an order different from how they are stored.  If the data pages do not fix in memory, then you have a situation called *thrashing*, which means that there is a high probability that each new row would be a cache miss.