# Planner Method Configuration per transaction

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres 11.x is there a way to configure the [query planner parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE) for a particular transaction?

For a particular query I would like to:

```
SET ENABLE_NESTLOOP TO FALSE;
... run special query
SET ENABLE_NESTLOOP TO TRUE;
```

Comment: What you have should work. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I can't see any mention in the documentation at what level the parameters are set. And based on other answers it sounds like the parameters are scoped to the session: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594930/what-are-the-pitfalls-of-setting-enable-nestloop-to-off

Comment: nvm I see it's described in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can easily be done with `SET LOCAL`:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = off;
SELECT ...;
COMMIT;
```

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) says:

> The effects of `SET LOCAL` last only till the end of the current transaction, whether committed or not.

Answer (score 0):

This information is described in the documentation for [SET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html)

> If SET (or equivalently SET SESSION) is issued within a transaction that is later aborted, the effects of the SET command disappear when the transaction is rolled back. Once the surrounding transaction is committed, the effects will persist until the end of the session, unless overridden by another SET.

In particular you can use `SET LOCAL`

> The effects of SET LOCAL last only till the end of the current transaction, whether committed or not.